# Find parent folders in list of paths

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list of folders like this:

```
u'Magazines/testfolder1',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/',
u'Magazines/testfolder2',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/',
u'Magazines/testfolder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/',
```

Now what I want is the list of only parent folders.

i.e in the example above I want that to reduce to:

```
u'Magazines/testfolder1',
u'Magazines/testfolder2',
u'Magazines/testfolder3',
```

because they all contain child folders.

I am recursively adding folders in My database so if I have `testfolder1` then script will automatically recurse its subfolders. So I don't need sub folders in the list if their parent is also in the list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [set](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#set):

```
>>> list_of_folders = [
...     u'Magazines/testfolder1',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/folder3',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder2',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/folder3',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder3',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/folder3',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/',
...     u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/',
... ]
>>> result = set()
>>> for folder in list_of_folders:
...     for parent in result:
...         if folder.startswith(parent):
...             break
...     else:
...         result.add(folder)
... 
>>> result
{'Magazines/testfolder3', 'Magazines/testfolder2', 'Magazines/testfolder1'}
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
list_of_folders = [
    ...
]
result = set()
for folder in list_of_folders:
    if all(not folder.startswith(parent) for parent in result):
        result.add(folder)
print result
```

Comment: I am getting empty set , i have made small script here http://codepad.org/CRGLJC4R . can u have a look

Comment: Outdent the final "else", it matches with the "for", not with the "if". And make sure you read the Python documentation to understand how that works.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, thanks but i don't get desired result if parent folder is not at top. i mean if you put `u'Magazines/testfolder1',` at the bottom then result is different e,g this http://codepad.org/0Te9aEmK

Comment: This solution worked for me if i ahve folders in any random order http://codepad.org/YXchgYhR but i am not sure if that is 100% correct

Comment: You don't really need an else here.

Comment: @Marcin, I used for .. else (not if .. else).  If you remove `else`, you get all paths.

Comment: What a confusing way to write this.

Comment: @Marcin, How can I improve **this**? (BTW, what is `this`? comemnt ? code)

Comment: @Marcin, do u have any other proper solution for this

Answer (score 0):

how about use [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
import re

l = [
    u'Magazines/testfolder1',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/',
]

expect = [
    u'Magazines/testfolder1',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3', 
]

result = filter(lambda x: re.match('^[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$', x), l)

assert expect == result
```

Answer (score 0):

Mate I beleive below is the solution you are looking for

```
lst = [
u'Magazines/testfolder1',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/',
u'Magazines/testfolder2',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/',
u'Magazines/testfolder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/folder3',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/',
u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/'
 ]

    for x in lst:
       for y in lst[:]: 
           if x in y and len(x)<len(y):
               lst.remove(y)
    print lst
```

**Output**

```
[u'Magazines/testfolder1', u'Magazines/testfolder2', u'Magazines/testfolder3']
```

This program iteratively removes the subfolders from your list , leaving behind only the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
l =[u'Magazines/testfolder1',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder1/folder1/folder2/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder2/folder1/folder2/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/folder3',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/',
    u'Magazines/testfolder3/folder1/folder2/', ]

mincount = min(s.count('/') for s in l)
[d for d in sorted(l) if d.count('/') <= mincount]
#=> [u'Magazines/testfolder1', u'Magazines/testfolder2', u'Magazines/testfolder3']
```

It's not excessively clever, but it works where there's a common root.

Comment: You assume that the parent folders contains only one '/' or no '/'. What if parents folder is `'a/b/c/d'`?

Comment: @falsetru The parent folder here is in fact `Magazines`. It's not a coherent task, anyway. If it really bothers you, you could find the smallest number of separators, and use that as the count.

Comment: if `l` is `['a', 'a/b', 'c/d']`, you will get `['a']`. But it should be `['a', 'c/d']`.

Comment: @falsetru Well that's a different task than the one posted.

Comment: @marcin if i had `u'Magazines/testfolder4/folder1/folder2/folder3',` at the bottom then it should show that as well but ur code does not show that. see here http://codepad.org/9lf5g5Qc

Comment: @fdsgds Your question asks for folders which contain child folders, which that does not.

Comment: @Marcin i think u are intelligent enough to see what i was looking for , rather than proving ur answer as right and my question is wrong